# Windows Mobile 6 Icon Transparency & SetColorKey

Tags: c#, graphics, windows-mobile, compact-framework, paint

I'm trying to draw rectangles in compact framework with images. My image attributes have the SetColorKey(Color.Mangenta,Color.Mangenta) and then I play with the rectangle color filling. Almost everything works, but my icon's border keeps getting Mangenta.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help understand why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. The border actually is not white or mangenta. It is another color to set the gradient. So, filling the border with mangenta makes everything work great. Thanks.